# LPTHW 43: function object has no attribute 'enter'

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, instance, instance-variables

I'm trying to break down lesson 43 of LPTHW to understand it better, and run each piece independently, and I can't understand why it is returning

```
PS C:\Python> python ex43.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex43.py", line 67, in <module>
    a_game.play()
  File "ex43.py", line 17, in play
    self.scene_map.opening_scene.enter()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'enter'
```

I'm trying to make it run *just* the first scene of my code, and just end up printing 'You've entered the central corridor' so that I can understand how each function is being called.

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint

class Scene(object):

  def enter(self):
      print "This scene is not yet configured. Subclass it and implement enter()."
    exit(1)


class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        self.scene_map.opening_scene.enter()

class Death(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass

class CentralCorridor(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "You've entered the central corridor."

class LaserWeaponArmory(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass

class TheBridge(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass


class EscapePod(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass


class Map(object):

    scenes = {
            'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
            'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
            'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
            'escape_pod': EscapePod()
            }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        return val

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.scene_map.opening_scene.enter(self.start_scene)

a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

When run it gives the error above. I guess I'm having trouble seeing how 'play' is starting the 'opening_scene'

Comment: Try replacing contents of `def play(self):` with `self.scene_map.opening_scene()`. What do you get from that?

Comment: I replaced what you suggested, replaced `def opening_scene(self)` with
`return self.opening_scene(self.start_scene)`  and it tells me
`TypeError: opening_scene() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`
If I change it to `def opening_scene(self, scene_name):` then it tells me
`TypeError: opening_scene() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`
It's like it takes 1 argument if  I give it 2 arguments, but it takes 2 arguments if I give it 1.

Comment: I didn't suggest any of those changes though. Specifically, have `def play(self):` and replace `self.scene_map.opening_scene.enter()` with `self.scene_map.opening_scene()`. What does that one change give you?

Comment: I only have access to Python 3.6 atm. If I make the change I suggested to you, I get `AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'scene_map'`. Is that what you see?

Comment: Also, is this the actual exercise code you've been given or is this your own coding attempt? It's unnecessarily convoluted with names being repeated. What is the objective of the exercise? IIRC, he's now put the exercises behind a paywall

Comment: Yep, that's what I see. When I remove scene_map I get the argument error.

Comment: This isn't the exact code I was given, I'm just trying to run this one scene independently so I can understand why it works at all, I'm at a spot where I'm supposed to figure it out by myself, and I've already cheated by looking enough so I want to be able to understand it better before I move on to all of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159320/discussion-between-chase-hippen-and-roganjosh).

Answer (score 0):

That's because all functions in python if you want to call them, execute them, you must use `()` so your code should be :

```
class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        self.scene_map.opening_scene().enter()
```

Or maybe just :

```
    def play(self):
        self.scene_map.opening_scene()
```

Comment: I think the idea of the exercise is to create namespace confusion, so you don't know whether you're looking at a class attribute or a method for another object.

Comment: I now have a new error popping up after executing it like that, it returns

"PS C:\Python> python ex43.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex43.py", line 67, in <module>
    a_game.play()
  File "ex43.py", line 17, in play
    self.scene_map.opening_scene()
  File "ex43.py", line 63, in opening_scene
    return self.scene_map.opening_scene.enter(self.start_scene)
AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'scene_map'
"

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find the answer via this thread : [r/learnpython](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/7dz2n1/im_having_trouble_with_lpthw_43_trying_to_run_the/)

Basically, I was calling 'opening_scene' within opening_scene' and instead I had to call the scene that is passed to Map via a.game.play() by `return self.scenes[self.start_scene].enter()` which will run 'enter()' for whatever scene it was passed. Since opening scene is set to be 'central_corridor' that's what it pulls out of the dictionary to run. I hope this makes sense and isn't as disjointed as it feels.